# Can there be a close reason on site metas for questions that don't provide evidence that a problem exists?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, meta, close-reasons

One of the things that really annoys me about meta is the amount of discussions that lack examples. This is annoying for two reasons:

1. Often, if a meta post can't provide evidence that something is a problem, the meta post is about a problem that doesn't actually exist. I've lost track of the amount of time the Literature site has wasted on, for example, tagging issues that are purely hypothetical<sup>[1](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/929/expand-scope-of-tag-the-art-of-war),[2](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153/what-are-the-recommended-literary-term-tags)</sup> (many of these issues have still not come up).

   Of course, if a hypothetical issue ever becomes a reality, these meta discussions are useless because...
2. It's impossible to make good decisions without examples of a problem. I've found that decisions made without examples are very hard to put into practice, because those decisions tend to ignore the various edge cases that examples would have revealed.

   A site I was active on, Interpersonal Skills, is an excellent example of why examples are important. See [Are examples strictly necessary on meta?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1791/are-examples-strictly-necessary-on-meta).

Enough time has been wasted. Could meta sites have a close reason for questions that lack examples?

Comment: Doesn't _Off Topic->The problem described here can no longer be reproduced. Changes to the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete. If you encounter a similar problem, please post a new question._ fit well?

Comment: @user0042 that appears to be a close reason for meta.stackexchange.com, not for any of the child metas. But that wording is also pretty technical; it might not work as well on non-technical sites. I would prefer for wording that specically uses the word examples.

Comment: And simply *Unclear* doesn't fly?

Comment: Declined for the reasons in Robert's answer. Probably more productive to focus on improving the specific guidance for meta participation and asking, particularly on younger sites.

Comment: @Shog9 I would like to see better guidance, because this is an issue I keep seeing on beta sites, and it's tiring to keep having to explain this when efforts would be better focused elsewhere. I'm not entirely sure whether the best place for that guidance would be. Perhaps in the ask a question dialogue?

Comment: Closing ain't gonna fix that. Current guidance reads, *"Provide details. Show examples. Whenever possible, link to the relevant questions, answers, users, or page on the site you're discussing."* - propose improvements to that.

Comment: @Shog9 a link to a page on the help center that explains *why* those examples are important would be nice. (I will admit that I hadn't seen that dialogue until you pointed it out to me).

Answer (score 14):

Long story short — we *used* to have a lot more close reasons covering the increasingly granular ways you might close a post. But with so many choices, the process was becoming too onerous.

We simplified that process because we found it **more engaging** to keep the choices simple so users would actually *talk* with each other to describe *where* the post went wrong, rather than dismissively rubber-stamping everything *"not allowed here."*

There's also a problem where explicit close reasons quickly become absolute doctrine. If you codify every possible way you can suck at Stack Exchange, there's a tendency to feel like — *"if <x> occurs, you **must** close".* Perhaps some issues are *self-evident* and no specific examples are needed. But enumerating everything that can possibly go wrong with a post has the unfortunate side effect of users actively patrolling for those reasons, and you start to dismiss posts out of hand whenever a matching ruleset fits.

If a post needs additional information to be clear, ask for it. Not everything needs to be codified into another reason to close a post. We went down that path in our early days, and it was more *dis-*​engaging than helpful.